# How do I configure proxy settings for install4j-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, install4j

I tried passing the proxy settings in via `<jvmArguments>` just like you do with an install4j-generated installer:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.install4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>install4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile-installers</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>
                    <arg>-DproxySet=true</arg>
                    <arg>-Dhttps.proxyHost=...</arg>
                    <arg>-Dhttps.proxyPort=443</arg>
                    <arg>-DproxyAuth=true</arg>
                    <arg>-DproxyAuthUser=${...}</arg>
                    <arg>-DproxyPassword=${...}</arg>
                </jvmArguments>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

but that failed.

On a machine where proxy settings are injected via the IDE, the above works, even if I intentionally pass in a wrong password or even a nonexistent proxy server, so I guess I'm Doing It Wrong(tm).

Comment: Try `-DproxyHost` and `-DproxyPort`, those are read by install4j.

Comment: Aww dammit, standard interpretation is to have separate settings for http and https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a misconfiguration.
Lesson to take home: If you see "connection refused", "forbidden", or any other connection failure messages, it might be the proxy or the target server talking, you don't know and the install4j-maven-plugin output does not tell you.
It would be nice if a future install4j-maven-plugin version could output that information, but currently it does not.